# Can't get dynamic print area working

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have just finished building a report which will have a variable number of entries and would like the print area to adjust dynamically.  The print area needs to run from B2 across to AD2, and down to the end of the data.  The data starts in cell C16.  There are formulas in cells on the main tab pulling data from other tabs and returning "" where no data is found, I think this is complicating matters.

I have tried various suggestions online but none seem to work with my sheet specifically.  Are there any experts out there that might be able to drop some knowledge my way? =)

Luke

Comment: I tried doing this with named ranges, but Excel converts it to a set range based on the reference.  Based on this I believe you will need a VBA solution to set the print range..  Alternatively you could define your print range and then insert your data betweent the limits of your print range.  This may cause your print range to expand automatically by the number of rows and columns added.

Comment: The data is dropped onto another tab and the dashboard tab is pulling through and making calculations, so no data is inserted as such.
Named ranges seems to be the recommended way of doing it and seems to work for most people using an offset with countif functions to define the range.  I'm not certain whether my formulas inserting "" into cells is causing the countifs to feed an incorrect number back meaning that I don't get the print range that I need.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it!  So the COUNTA functions in the named range creating the dynamic print area were counting the cells that had formulas in them when they were outputting "".  So I changed the COUNTA functions to COUNT functions, and changed the formulas to refer to a fixed cell with 1 in it.  The formulas then output 1 if the row is populated with data, but the 1 is formatted to be the same colour as the background so are not visible.  This then allows the COUNT function to create the dynamic print range =)

For those interested, my working dynamic print range ended up looking like this:

=OFFSET(Dash!$B$2,0,0,COUNT(Dash!$B$2:$B$70),COUNT(Dash!$B$2:$AD$2))

I hope someone finds this helpful if they experience a similar issue to me!